# How we get to find the result of this limit?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, summation

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2n-1}\right)=\text{ ?}$$
I don't know how we get to find the result of this operation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 (-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}\,dx= \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-x^2)^{n-1}dx= \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx= \cdots\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: How you obtain the second equality?

Comment: and $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-x^2\right)^{n-1}=\:\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ ? how you do that?

Comment: heyy dude, if I put every value from sum don't will be 1/1-u... I verify

Comment: I've right was a geometric series, but your formula is for general case? cause I obtain $\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}$

Comment: You got to take the limit: $\dfrac{1-u^n}{1-u} \to \dfrac{1}{1-u}$

Comment: so if we did not have limit,that value for the sum $\frac{1}{1-u}$ was not good?

Comment: You can't get the answer if you don't take the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the Taylor series for $\tan^{-1}x$ is:
$$x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\ldots$$

It follows that the given limit is equal to exactly $\tan^{-1}1=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: In my book this is solve with integral... I am a student, I never work with Taylor series

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series expansion of $\displaystyle\tan^{-1}(x)$ is:
$\displaystyle\tan^{-1}(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\ldots+\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} \cdot \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$
Limit you are trying to calculate is simply $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty }\tan^{-1}(1)$.


Hence,
$\displaystyle\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+...+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2n-1}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: But without Taylor series, because I don't work with this, I am a student!!!

Comment: All answers are based on Taylor series, give me an example without this method with a recurrence relation, something else

Comment: @Lucas do you at least know the integral?  Then it can be explained without Taylor

Comment: Vim if you know something else to make clever with me very good, look here and help http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1210854/edit , otherwise shut up, thank you :)

Comment: @Lucas. Please don't make assumptions.  Well I don't mean to make clever with you. I was just saying that it could be explained without Taylor , since you didn't know that , but required the knowledge of this integral.  BTW, if you want to reply to my comment, you should at least @ me in your comment.  Otherwise I will never ever get informed.

Comment: sorry dude, I think you want to make clever with me... Look here, maybe can help you:  $I_n=\int _0^1\:\frac{x^n}{x^2+1}dx$; and that relation for recurrence: $I_{2n}\:\cdot \:\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\:=\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{2n-1}-\:\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\cdot I_{2n-2}$